# laravel error in deleting the parent row data

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete, laravel-5.5

I want to delete campaign but not delete the campaign and following error occurs.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`demopurpose_fundraising`.`campaign_product`, CONSTRAINT
>   `campaign_product_campaign_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`)
>   REFERENCES `campaign` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `campaign` where `id`
>   = 60)

campaign table schema :

```
Schema::create('campaign', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('campaign_name');
            $table->float('campaign_goal',8,2);
            $table->string('discription',400);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->date('start_date');
            $table->date('end_date');
            $table->float('total_fund',8,2);
});
```

campaign_product table schema :

```
Schema::create('campaign_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('campaign_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaign')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('product')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: You cannot delete the parent entry if there are child in other table. what you can do is create a cascade method. That way MySQL will delete the child entries first then delete the parent row that you want to remove

Comment: i am new in laravel. plz provide the code for it..@ReyNorbertBesmonte

Answer (score 2):

You should update your migrations to do something on delete. See: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys

for example (from the docs)

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

depending on your db of choice, there may be other options, like set null.

The issue here is you set a constraint and yet you are surprised to be constrained. Set an onDelete behaviour so the db does the handling for you.

Comment: I also use ondelete with my schema and it cannot delete give me the same error that u got when i use this $user->activities()->delete(); then delete the user and it all data but when i simply use $user->delete(); it shows the error Please help